# Regex e-mail validating with Æ Ø Å

Tags: regex, email

I need to validate a email address the best way, and I need to include some danish characters:

> Æ Ø Å
>
> æ ø å

My current regex is:

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

How to incorporate the extra letters, and is there any optimizing that can be done to ensure the best handling of the e-mail address?

Comment: Even when this is fixed your regular expression will still fail to match some valid email addresses.

Comment: What exactly is "the best way"?

Comment: Don't waste your time writing a "specific" validator for e-mail addresses. It has no benefit over a cursory check (`^.*@.*\..*$`), but with the length and complexity of the regex the chance for false negatives rises because you did not think of everything. *(And frankly, if people enter invalid or false e-mail addresses, it's their problem, right? So why bother.)*

Comment: @Tomalak: you forgot a dot: `@^.*@.*\..*$`

Comment: @Bart: No I didn't. :-D (thanks to the 5 minute period where you can still edit your comment...)

Comment: @Tomalak: I knew you'd do that, that's why I already "upped" your comment! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Email address validation is hard with regular expressions.

A simple version could be:

```
^[ÆØÅæøåA-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[ÆØÅæøåA-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$
```

but this will fail on some valid addresses like `Tim\ O'Reilly@microsoft.com` or `me@1.2.3.4`, and match lots of invalid addresses like `here@there.where`.

In any way, you have to send an e-mail to it and get a response before you really know whether an address is valid or not.